# Rails, Mongoid: use custom key and custom key format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, key, mongoid

I have model `Account`:

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  ...
end
```

I want to use specific ids with specific format. I want id to be 16-digits instead of `4ceede9b5e6f991aef000007`, something like that: `1111222233334444`.

What is the best practice to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If the id is a simple number, try:

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  identity :type => Integer
end

account = Account.new :id => 1111222233334444
#=> #<Account _id: 1111222233334444, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
account.save
#=> true 
account
#=> #<Account _id: 1111222233334444, created_at: 2010-11-26 00:48:27 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-26 00:48:27 UTC> 
Account.count
#=> 1 
Account.first
#=> #<Account _id: 1111222233334444, created_at: 2010-11-26 00:48:27 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-26 00:48:27 UTC>
```

If you want to use letters in the id too, you can do `identity :type => String` instead.